# Javascript trouble in dynamically call another class in other js file

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I'm trying to make a `javascript` function to call another `.js` file like this:

```
scriptCaller.js

function callScript(file){
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.id = file;
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.async = true;
   script.src = "script/"+file+".js";
   document.getElementById('scriptSection').appendChild(script);
}
```

Then I create some class to be called by that script in other file:

```
divGenerator.js

function divGenerator(){
   var self = this;
   var div = document.createElement('div');

   this.tag = function(){
       return div;
   }

   /*and some other function to style the div*/

}
```

Then i make the main file to be executed:

```
main.js

function build(){
   callScript('divGenerator');
}

function main(){
   var test = new divGenerator();

   /*execute some function to style the div*/

   document.getElementById('htmlSection').appendChild(script);
}
```

All the three file will be called in a `HTML` files that will execute the main function:

```
myPage.html

<html>
   <head>
      <title>myPage</title>
   </head>
   <script src="scriptCaller.js"></script>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
   <body>
      <div id="htmlSection"></div>
      <div id="scriptSection"></div>
   </body>
</html>
<script>build();</script>
<script>main();</script>
```

If I correct it should display the styled div, but what I got is an error that said:

> TypeError: divGenerator is not a constructor[Learn More]

But, when I move the `divGenerator()` class to `myPage.html` it works fine. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: From your browser's console, can you share which line is throwing this error? `TypeError: Container is not a constructor[Learn More]`

Comment: @gurvinder372 it says in main.js:10:13. the line that declare var test = new divGenerator();

Comment: which line, mention that specific line

Comment: @gurvinder372 this line -> var test = new divGenerator();

Comment: You need to drill that error description further.. I can't see `Container` in your code.. For reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor

Comment: @gurvinder372 that Container means the divGenerator(). I use different naming in this question.. Sorry, i forgot to replace that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have couple of problems in your code. First of all, do not assign id to script element same as the "exported" global constructor name. You need to remember that anything with `id` attribute (and `name`) automatically gets exposed as global variable on `window` object. It means that `divGenerator` in your case is going to be reference to HTMLScriptElement, not a constructor function.

Second problem is related to timing, since you are loading script with `async` attribute. This is good, but you need to realise that in this case you can't expect that script will be loaded when you call `main` after `build()`. I would suggest to wrap script creation into promise:

```
function callScript(file){
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.id = 'script-' + file; // Note different id
       script.async = true;
       script.src = "script/" + file + ".js";
       script.onload = resolve

       document.getElementById('scriptSection').appendChild(script);
   })
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<script>
  build().then(function() {
    main();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Aww.. a new error comes up. it says TypeError: build(...) is undefined[Learn More].

Comment: You still need to include `<script src="main.js"></script>` where `build` is defined.

Comment: it works fine after i change the build() function with callScript('divGenerator'). Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `scriptCaller.js` and `divGenerator.js` to your html script element.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>myPage</title>
   </head>
   <script src="scriptCaller.js"></script>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
   <script src="scriptCaller.js"></script>
   <script src="divGenerator.js"></script>
   <body>
      <div id="htmlSection"></div>
      <div id="scriptSection"></div>
   </body>
</html>
<script>build();</script>
<script>main();</script>
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question.